# How to style ASPX radial buttons using data value fields

Tags: css, asp.net, styles

I have this code and I can't style it I want to move the padding-right at least 15PX.

```html
   <td >
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoFrequency" runat="server" class="radio" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataValueField="EmailNotificationFrequency_ID" DataTextField="EmailNotificationFrequency" Width="150" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" onclick="javascript:clearMessage();" />
                    </td>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMoWE.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
just style using the class called radio
```

```css
.radio
{
 padding-right: 15px;
}
```

}